# I want to add user manually into Firebase and try to login into my app but getting error like "PLEASE VERIFY YOUR EMAIL TO LOGIN"

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I have added the EMAIL VERIFICATION PART in my project.

So every user need to verify their email before login.

But I want to add some user manually in Firebase, and I did that also into my project and I successfully added that.
BUT main problems is that when I try to LOGIN using that email I am having error message like "Please verify your email...".

But as I told you earlier I added user manually in Firebase, so I didn't receive any verification email into that perticular account.

So is there any way to login using manually added users into my app?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to mark a user as verified that you added in the Firebase console, which I answered below. Note that double/triple punctuation and the use of all-caps hurt the readability of your question, so I removed/reduced those. Please keep this in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication doesn't check anywhere whether the user has verified their email address. So if your app shows a message to that effect, it's either your application code, or a library that you use, that is show the message.

Normally a user's email address is only changed to verified if they follow the flow outlined in [sending a user a verification email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email). You can do this from your application in the same place where it now detects that the user is not verified.

Alternatively, you can mark the user as verified using the Admin SDK, after adding them in the console. For an example of how to do this, see [update a user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) in the documentation. Keep in mind: the Admin SDKs can only be run in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.